# Admob Site URL with Amazon Apps

Tags: url, admob, ads

I'm in the process of porting an app from Google Play to Amazon and I've read Amazon Apps also support Admob.  My question is must I "Add Site/App" with Admob for the Amazon build and if so should the "Site URL" be

`amzn://apps/android?p=com.MySiteName.MyAppName`

rather than

`market://details?id=com.MySiteName.MyAppName`

Thanks,
Nick

Answer (score 0):

You can just use your market url and/or use the same AdMob site id in your amazon and Google Play builds.

Answer (score 0):

You can use in the Site URL:

http://www.amazon.com/gp/mas/dl/android?p=[your.package.name.here]

Source: https://developer.amazon.com/appsandservices/community/post/Tx3A1TVL67TB24B/Linking-To-the-Amazon-Appstore-for-Android